# Do I need to ensure ThreadPool threads have returned before exiting main (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, threadpool

I cannot find a straight answer to this. I know that for ordinary threads that you create and control in C++, you must either join or detach them before exiting main. (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/176290/)

But for thread pools (in which the programmer doesn't explicitly manage the threads), specifically with regard to the Win32 ThreadPool API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pool-api): Do you have to ensure that no threads in the threadpool are running when the process terminates? And what happens if main exits while a worker thread callback is being executed in the threadpool created in main?

If one of the worker callbacks has an infinite loop, does that change anything?

Comment: *"you must call join on them [...]; otherwise the process crashes"* - I doubt this is accurate. It seems like you are attributing C++' `thread` implementation to the system. This is not the case. You can `CreateThread` as many threads as you wish, and then return from your entry point, which has the same effect as terminating the process.

Comment: When you return from the main (first) thread of your process, the process will be terminated, no matter how many other threads it has.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I added specific context for C++ threading. Disregard my previous comment that I deleted.

Comment: The thread pool is not part of the C++ language specification, so you have to go to the specific documentation for the thread pool. (Answer: The thread pool terminates all active threads at process termination.)